# How to keep edited values in an output datatable using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny app to add all input variables to a datatable.
I also have another button used to enable a second tabPanel and shows an editable datatable.
I would like to edit the table in the second tabPanel and update the datatable. So, when I continue to add more values it can keep the updates that have been done.

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("DT")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "idTabset",
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_data",
      title = "Inpute Data",
      textInput(inputId   = 'item1', label = 'Item 1'),
      textInput(inputId   = 'item2', label = 'Item 2'),
      actionButton('save_data', 'Add'),
      actionButton('review_data', 'Save and Review')
    ),
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_tbl",
      title = "Raw Data",
      DT::dataTableOutput('output_tbl'),
      actionButton('submit_tbl', 'Upload')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hideTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  
  user_tbl <- tibble(`Item 1` = as.character(),
                     `Item 2` = as.character())
  
  user_data <- reactive({
    tibble(`Item 1` = as.character(input$item1),
           `Item 2` = as.character(input$item2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save_data, {
    user_tbl <<- user_tbl %>%
      bind_rows(user_data())
    
    output$output_tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(user_tbl, editable = TRUE)
      
    })
    
    sapply(c('item1','item2'),
           function(x) {updateTextInput(session, x, value = "")})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$review_data, {
    showTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone know how to keep the updated values?

### Update: Thanks to @YBS

I am also creating the `user_tbl` outside, so I don't need to use a `reactiveValues` to assign the results.

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("DT")

user_tbl <- data.frame(`Item 1` = as.character(),
                   `Item 2` = as.character(),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "idTabset",
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_data",
      title = "Inpute Data",
      textInput(inputId   = 'item1', label = 'Item 1'),
      textInput(inputId   = 'item2', label = 'Item 2'),
      actionButton('save_data', 'Add'),
      actionButton('review_data', 'Save and Review')
    ),
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_tbl",
      title = "Raw Data",
      DT::dataTableOutput('output_tbl'),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hideTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  
  user_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(`Item 1` = as.character(input$item1),
           `Item 2` = as.character(input$item2),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save_data, {
    user_tbl <<- user_tbl %>%
      bind_rows(user_data())
    
    output$output_tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(user_tbl, editable = TRUE)
      
    })
    
    sapply(c('item1','item2'), function(x) {updateTextInput(session, x, value = "")})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$output_tbl_cell_edit, {
    info = input$output_tbl_cell_edit
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    user_tbl[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, user_tbl[i, j])
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$review_data, {
    showTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please consider posting a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that someone can help you.

Comment: I've removed unnecessary code, hope it is MRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `table_cell_edit` feature of `DT`.  You need a `reactiveValues` object to keep track of changes in tab1 and tab2.  Try this

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("DT")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "idTabset",
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_data",
      title = "Inpute Data",
      textInput(inputId   = 'item1', label = 'Item 1'),
      textInput(inputId   = 'item2', label = 'Item 2'),
      actionButton('save_data', 'Add'),
      actionButton('review_data', 'Save and Review')
    ),
    tabPanel(
      value = "input_tbl",
      title = "Raw Data",
      DT::dataTableOutput('output_tbl'),
      actionButton('submit_tbl', 'Upload')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hideTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  
  user_tbl <- tibble(`Item 1` = as.character(),
                     `Item 2` = as.character())
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(data=user_tbl)
  
  user_data <- reactive({
    tibble(`Item 1` = as.character(input$item1),
           `Item 2` = as.character(input$item2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save_data, {
    rv$data <<- rv$data %>%
      bind_rows(user_data())
    output$output_tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(rv$data, editable = TRUE)
      
    })
    
    sapply(c('item1','item2'),
           function(x) {updateTextInput(session, x, value = "")})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$output_tbl_cell_edit, {
    info = input$output_tbl_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value

    rv$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rv$data[i, j])

  })
  
  observeEvent(input$review_data, {
    showTab(inputId = "idTabset", target = "input_tbl")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That works. Instead of using ```rv <- reactiveValues(data=user_tbl)``` I can just create that data outside and it works as the same way. Thanks for letting me know about the ```table_cell_edit``` feature.